# Networkx and matplotlib colormap for nodes ; same map for different networks

Tags: nodes, networkx, colormap

I'm struggling to display nodes colors when plotting several networks. basically, I start with a dataframe looking like this :

```
data.head()

    x     y     C1    C2    C3    C4            
n1  0.63  0.34  1.00  1.00  1.00  1.07
n2  0.56  0.27  0.94  0.91  0.94  1.11
n3  0.59  0.26  1.07  1.02  1.05  1.21
n4  0.65  0.38  1.15  1.27  1.55  0.98
n5  0.63  0.44  0.93  0.89  0.99  1.04
```

Each line is a network node (the edges list is stored in another file) and I use the `x` and `y` columns as the nodes layout. My point is to plot four time the network, with nodes colors following the values of each of the four columns `C1/C1/C3/C4`.

So, to compare easily the evolution of the value of each node, I tried to define the range of the colormap with the min an max values of the four columns (hard-coded in the code sample below) when plotting the network :

```
cmap = plt.cm.YlOrRd
vmin, vmax = 0.0, 200.0
nodes_colors = data['C1'] # or C2,C3,C4
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(my_network, 
                       pos=my_positions_dict, 
                       node_size=200, 
                       edgecolors='black',
                       node_color=nodes_colors,                            
                       cmap=cmap, 
                       vmin=vmin, 
                       vmax=vmax)
```

But it does not work ! I have a few nodes with high values only, so it easy to check manually, and the colors are wrong. What did I do wrong with this first attempt ?

I tried another way, by using `ScalarMappable`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cmap = plt.cm.YlOrRd
vmin = 0.0
vmax = 200.0
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))
```

But then I do not know how to use this when plotting the network. Could it work like this ?

Unfortunately I did not share a reproducible code because I have a lot of pre-treatment of the input data (which, moreover, are not public for now).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a problem of index order and nodes order between the dataframe and the network. Sorry for asking silly questions.